# c++ automatic template deduction fails for template argument

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to better understand why automatic template deduction (applied when compiled with `g++ -std=c++17`) works in the first three lines in `main()`, but fails in the fourth. Is there any chance it will be accepted by compilers in the near future?

```
template <typename P = void>
class A {
public:
    void f1() {}
};

template<typename C>
void g() {}


int main() {
    A<> a;       // works
    A aa;        // works
    g<A<>>();    // works
    g<A>();      // fails
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `A` is not a type. It is a template for a type.

Comment: there is nothing to deduce. `A` refers to the template, not to an instantiation.

Comment: I think the main question here is why `A a` works but `g<A>` does not. Which is (of course) in agreement with the standard, but you'd have a hard time convincing anyone that it is intuitive (not that C++ tries hard on that front).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a matter of signature. Basically you're passing the wrong type.

Both `A a` and `A<> a` mean you want an instance of `A` with the default template parameter value, that is, you end up with `A< void >`.

The function `g< C >()` accepts a template parameter which happens to be a type, not another templated type. When you invoke it with `A<>`, you tell the compiler that you want to use "the instantiation" of the templated type `A`, which is valid. When you invoke it with `A` you tell the compiler you want to invoke `g< C >()` with `C` being a templated type which does not fit its signature.

If you declare/define `g()` like so `template <typename <typename> TTemplatedType> g()` it will accepts to be invoked like this `g< A >()` but `g< A<> >()` will fail because now it no longer wants something else than a templated type.

Comment: I think your last paragraph is unnecessary. The question is about the (more or less unexpected) difference between `A a` and `g<A>`. The fact that `A` and `A<>` are both accepted in the first but suddenly "A is a template, not a type" in the second (if that was the reason, why did it work the first time?) is just not at all obvious. I'm aware that's what's correct according to the standard and C++ is not trying to be very intuitive, but your last sentence may just come off as condescending.

Comment: @MaxLanghof got it. Thanks for reporting me both your ideas and what you felt.

Answer (score 3):

With C++17, template argument deduction is also performed when the name of a class template is used as the type of an object being constructed.

Nothing changes for explicit type inside template.